# Mongoose/ MongoDB: Get _ids from names

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Given an array of strings and a collection with that string and primary key in MongoDB, how can I get the _id's of those strings if exists and insert a record if not present in the collection?

The collection has only name and its _id in it.